# NodeJS Mongodriver Aggregate with lookup makes unwanted inner join

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

First of all thank you for reading this.

I'm trying to left outer join my Product's documents with the User's collection documents, by user ID but somehow I can't do it, there are missing fields and the join is not succesful. I'm quite new in mongodb so can somebody explain please what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

products collection:

```
_id:ObjectId("60723aac4636d52de87c1496")
Title:My first product
Category: Car
Model: BMW
userId:"6060d3cd8231610848942f69" <--it is a string
...otherfields

_id:ObjectId("60723afe4636d52de87c1497")
Title:My first product
Category: Car
Model: Volkswagen
userId:"6060d3cd8231610848942f69" <--it is a string
...otherfields
```

my users collection:

```
_id:ObjectId("6060d3cd8231610848942f69")
username:"test"
email:"something@gmail.com"
password:"2131233 it's a hashed password"
__v:0

...other users
```

in my code:

```
export const getAllProducts = async () => {
    const db=getDB()
    const product= db.collection('products')

    const result= await product.aggregate([
        {"$project":{"userId":{"$toObjectId":"$userId"}}},
        {"$lookup": { "from": "users", "localField": "userId", "foreignField": "_id", "as": "users" }},
        {$unwind:"$users"},
      ]).toArray();
    
    return result
}

export const getProducts = (req,res) => {
        const result =  getAllProducts()
        result.then( (products) =>{
            console.log("Products=",products)
            return res.status(200).json({ success:true, products });
        })
        .catch( () => {
            res.status(400).json({ success: false});
        })

}
```

The result:

```
Products= [
  {
    _id: 60723aac4636d52de87c1496,
    userId: 6060d3cd8231610848942f69,
    users: {
      _id: 6060d3cd8231610848942f69,
      username: 'teszt2',
      email: 'asd@yahoo.com',
      password: '$2a$12$cBsvzuqdoXhECLhb.xn1.Ok6rXRjYIRmGwmbzPUW5HcWICLTUk7oO',
      __v: 0
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 60723afe4636d52de87c1497,
    userId: 6060d3cd8231610848942f69,
    users: {
      _id: 6060d3cd8231610848942f69,
      username: 'teszt2',
      email: 'asd@yahoo.com',
      password: '$2a$12$cBsvzuqdoXhECLhb.xn1.Ok6rXRjYIRmGwmbzPUW5HcWICLTUk7oO',
      __v: 0
    }
  },
]
```

Edit: My solution:

```
export const getAllProducts = async () => {
    const db=getDB()
    const product= db.collection('products')

    const result= await product.aggregate([
        {$addFields: {"_userId": { $toObjectId: "$userId" }}},
        {"$lookup": { "from": "users", "localField": "_userId", "foreignField": "_id", "as": "users" }},
        {$unwind:"$users"},
      ]).toArray();
    
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addFields stage is converting the `_id` field in the products document from ObjectID to String.

The Lookup stage is then joining the `userId` field from the products document with the `_id` field from the users document.

So the userId is still String and the users _id is still ObjectID, and therefore they don't match.

You could used [$toObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/) in the project stage to convert `userId` to an ObjectId, but you may want to consider using [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#mongodb-expression-exp.-convert) so that you can handle any documents that don't have a valid ObjectId string in the userId field.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now what was wrong and I also fixed it. Just a quick question should I use the addFields stage option for this or there is a more simple way for converting/joining?

Comment: Yes, addFields is the right stage to use.